# Discord.py ctx.author.id is not woring

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So here's my code, some part are messy because im so angry, error message in the end:

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord
import random
from keep_alive import keep_alive
import json
import os
import asyncio
#Game variables and list:
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')
#Game code here:

def o_acc(ctx):
    users = await gbd()

    if str(ctx.author.id) in users:
      return False
    else:
      users[str(ctx.author.id)] = {}
      users[str(ctx.author.id)]["Wallet"] = 10000
      with open("user.json", 'w') as f:
        json.dump(users, f)

      return True

def gbd():
  users = json.load(open("user.json", 'r'))
  return users

#Check balance command
@bot.command(name='bal')
async def balance(ctx):
  await o_acc(ctx.author)
  users = await gbd()

  em = discord.Embed(title = f"{ctx.message.author.name}'s balance'")
  em.add_field(name = 'Wallet balance', value = users[str(ctx.message.author.id)]['wallet'])
  await ctx.send(embed = em)
#These commands should be keep in the end!!!!
bot.run('token(bot showing')
```

Error message:File "main.py", line 32, in balance await o_acc(ctx.author) File "main.py", line 15, in o_acc if str(ctx.author.id) in users: AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'author'

Answer (score 1):

Just pass in `ctx` instead of `ctx.author` as the argument for `o_acc()`.

```py
#Check balance command
@bot.command(name='bal')
async def balance(ctx):
  await o_acc(ctx)
  users = await gbd()

  em = discord.Embed(title = f"{ctx.message.author.name}'s balance'")
  em.add_field(name = 'Wallet balance', value = users[str(ctx.message.author.id)]['wallet'])
  await ctx.send(embed = em)
```